# Clear Chrome Browser Cache using Nightwatch

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, nightwatch.js, shadow-dom

Using Nightwatch I am trying to clear the browser cache of Chrome which means I have to click the Confirm button on the settings page and therefore wait for it to be present. (chrome://settings/clearBrowserData)

Because Chrome is using shadow-roots this isn't as simple as selecting the element using the id.

Until just a few days ago the following worked just fine.

```
client.init('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData')
  .waitForElementPresent('* /deep/ #clearBrowsingDataConfirm', 20000)
  .moveToElement('* /deep/ #clearBrowsingDataConfirm', 5, 5)
  .mouseButtonClick(0)
```

I assume due to an automatic update of Chrome this now does not work anymore locally whereas on our Jenkins where we have a fixed Chrome version this still works.

The question now is whether there is an alternative to this. CSS doesn't seem to have an alternative to the /deep/ selector so I thought XPath might be a solution but either I tried it the wrong way or it just isn't.

Another possibility might be to somehow go down the tree shadow-root by shadow-root just like the constructed query by Chrome when copying the JS-Path of the specific element:

```
document.querySelector('body > settings-ui').shadowRoot.querySelector('#main').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-basic-page').shadowRoot.querySelector('#advancedPage > settings-section:nth-child(1) > settings-privacy-page').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-clear-browsing-data-dialog').shadowRoot.querySelector('#clearBrowsingDataConfirm')
```

Unfortunately I don't yet know Nightwatch well enough to adapt this to Nightwatch.

Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve clearing the browser cache with Nightwatch?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by clearing the cache?

Comment: @StratosIon We have a webapp on which you can log in with various users but the cache needs to be cleared in order to be able to log in with another user. Somewhere the old user is stored but we couldn't figure out where and clearing the cache solved the problem. Hope that kind of makes sense, sorry if it does not.

Ps. It is not as urgent anymore since we have solved it now by just moving the cursor to the position where the button should be. Awful solution which only works as long as the popup is the same size but at the moment it does work^^

Comment: I am asking because normally, unless configured otherwise, nightwatch will launch a new browser with a new sessions for every test.

Comment: @StratosIon Ah okay, good to know. But does that include Kerberos sso state? That's what's eventually used on our login. Either way thanks for your help, I'll follow up on that.

Comment: I would think yes, since the browser that selenium launches doesn't have any sessions attached to it

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = {
  "@tags": ["EXAMPLE"],
  "Clear Chrome Browser Cache": function (browser) {
    browser
      .url("chrome://settings/clearBrowserData")
      .waitForElementVisible("body")
      .execute(
        function () {
          return document
            .querySelector("settings-ui")
            .shadowRoot.querySelector("settings-main")
            .shadowRoot.querySelector("settings-basic-page")
            .shadowRoot.querySelector(
              "settings-section > settings-privacy-page"
            )
            .shadowRoot.querySelector("settings-clear-browsing-data-dialog")
            .shadowRoot.querySelector("#clearBrowsingDataDialog")
            .querySelector("#clearBrowsingDataConfirm");
        },
        [],
        function (clearData) {
          const clearDataButton = element(clearData.value);
          clearDataButton.click();
        }
      )
  },
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).